# Eclipse pydev 'F3' doesn't jump to definition

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've started using eclipse pydev for some django projects which is pretty decent, but when I press 'F3' instead of bringing me to the function definition, it jumps to the import statement on top, e.g.

```
from anotherfolder.file import myfunction
```

What should I do to get it jumping to the correct place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi it's been a while but I thought I just post my solution here for reference.

Go to Project >> Properties >> PyDev - PYTHONPATH
and add the django root folder to the project source folders if it's not already there.

The 'F3' go-to-definition should work across different modules in your django app now.